# Installing GCC correctly

Tags: python

I'm writing this as an utter Ubuntu newbie. I want to run the script found on [Save points to a shapefile with GDAL](http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/gdal-shapefile-points-save.html). But I get the following error, yes this error is similar to the question posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21269/error-installing-gdal-1-9-0-python-package). Stick with me.

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import point_store
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "point_store.py", line 3, in <module>
import osgeo.ogr
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in      
<module>
_gdal = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in     
swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/_gdal.so: symbol  
VSIFTruncateL, version GDAL_1.8 not defined in file libgdal.so.1 with link 
time reference
```

After reading the question I reference above I tried this:

```
sudo pip install GDAL==1.8.1
```

And then I got the following error:

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for   
Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:149:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or 
directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can get my gcc to happy fun times? There are lots of forum posts around about this error but I'm still looking for that "aha" moment.

Comment: As a guess, try `sudo apt-get install build-essential python-all-dev`

Comment: I am now able to run the script I mentioned above sans any gcc error - I downloaded Ubuntu and all the other necessary programs onto my other computer.  This is not really a solution but I'm glad to have an option for utilizing gcc and python now.

Comment: @PattyJula what ubuntu did you use? I got the same exact problem, but I don't want to re-install everything...

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu the safest way is always to rely on the package manager, then everything just works. I strongly recommend to install the GDAL Python bindings using `apt-get` instead of `pip`, try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gdal
```

Comment: Thank you for the responses webrian and @Mike Toews. I tried your suggestions, restarted my computer, and am still getting the same error. I also wanted to mention that when I ran the script I referenced the first time, it worked just fine! I ran it several times using different coordinates even. I am open to other ideas on how to get everything set up properly, should there be other thoughts.