# Where can I find a python GDAL 1.8.0 package?

Tags: gdal, linux, python-2.7

I have python 2.7.4 installed on my RHEL 5 machine along with gdal-devel-1.8.0 and gdal-1.8.0. I tried to install the GDAL 1.9.1 package available on python's page (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/1.9.1) but got errors that are related to trying to install v1.9.1 when my gdal libraries are 1.8.0 (see [Error installing GDAL 1.9.0 python package](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21269/error-installing-gdal-1-9-0-python-package)). I can't find any other versions of python GDAL bindings. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Is there a `gdal-python` package available as well? that's how its usually installed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries.  This gives you links to GDAL binaries for all sorts of operating systems and the first item is for ELGIS, supposedly including RHEL.  Also see [here](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Enterprise_Linux_GIS).

I mostly use Windows and get my binaries from the excellent gisinternals link further down the page, so I can't vouch for the binaries, but since the links are from osgeo, I'd expect them to be good.

Comment: Thanks but I have the GDAL libraries/binaries installed for ELGIS already (v1.8.0 available at that website). The problem is that the only python package (bindings) I can find are for version 1.9.1 and apparently they are not backward compatible. I need python bindings for 1.8.0.